# Scheduling a long running task in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am very new in Azure. I have got a requirement to extract all ADO Workitems for all projects under the domain. I did it using WIQL and personal access token in C#. But the extraction takes around 1 hr to fetch everything for the last few years. Thats fine..

But the trouble is I have no idea how to make it schedule to run early morning every day (Outside business hours). Earlier we have got a dedicated server and thus I made the app a console app and used Task scheduler to run that every morning. But in Azure, please suggest a best and easy solution.

Developed in .NET Core 3.0

Comment: Check out Azure Functions and WebJobs. Azure Batch would be an overkill. If nothing else, you can still run your code as is in an Azure VM.

Comment: Sorry to ask because I am just a beginner.. Which is the best you suggest among these.. Also does Azure VM costs a lot?

Comment: `Which is the best you suggest among these` - This is something you would have to explore yourself as you know your application best. I can only recommend services suitable to run background services in Azure. VMs could cost a lot if used inappropriately however in your case you can only run the VM when your task is running and then shut down. That would be very cost effective.

Comment: Thats awesome mate.. Will check that

Comment: You can create a Azure Time triggered function (check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp)). You can host the function on consumption plan so that it would be cost effective.

Comment: @user1672994 - The problem with simple Functions is that they have an upper limit on execution time (5 or 10 minutes maximum).

Answer (score 1):

Azure webjobs will solve this problem you can enable the trigger to run automatically. Follow below article for step by step:

[Micorsoft Document Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

Using CRON jobs you step the schedule your task early morning

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, you can [create a azure timer trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) with cron expression which you want. Do your task in function code, the function will be executed according to the cron expression.

When you create the function app, please choose app service plan but not consumption plan because function in consumption plan can just run maximum 10 minutes and you mentioned your task will take about 1 hour. So choose app service plan and set the value of property `functionTimeout` as `-1` in the [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) of your function.

By the way, you'd better also enable "Always on" of your function app because you need the function long running.

[image]